# Solana Test Program Anchor Test failing tsconfig.json" > needs an import assertion of type "json"

Tags: testing, rust, anchor, smartcontracts, solana

I ran anchor test --skip-deploy and all it should do is initialize my program, but all I get is this error, that I cannot resolve. I checked the tsconfig.json settings they should be fine. This is just the default anchor setup and I'm not importing any unusual JSON files anywhere.

> anchor test --skip-deploy BPF SDK:
> /Users/julia/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.9.5/solana-release/bin/sdk/bpf
> cargo-build-bpf child: rustup toolchain list -v cargo-build-bpf child:
> cargo +bpf build --target bpfel-unknown-unknown --release warning:
> unused variable: `ctx`  --> programs/feeRedeemCounter/src/lib.rs:8:23
> | 8 |     pub fn initialize(ctx: Context) -> ProgramResult
> {   |                       ^^^ help: if this is intentional, prefix
> it with an underscore: `_ctx`   |   = note:
> `#[warn(unused_variables)]` on by default
>
> warning: `feeRedeemCounter` (lib) generated 1 warning
> Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 1.28s cargo-build-bpf child:
> /Users/julia/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.9.5/solana-release/bin/sdk/bpf/dependencies/bpf-tools/llvm/bin/llvm-readelf
> --dyn-symbols /Users/julia/Downloads/anchorTutorial/feeRedeemCounter/target/deploy/fee_redeem_counter.so
>
> To deploy this program:   $ solana program deploy
> /Users/julia/Downloads/anchorTutorial/feeRedeemCounter/target/deploy/fee_redeem_counter.so
> The program address will default to this keypair (override with
> --program-id):   /Users/julia/Downloads/anchorTutorial/feeRedeemCounter/target/deploy/fee_redeem_counter-keypair.json
> yarn run v1.22.17 warning package.json: No license field $
> /Users/julia/Downloads/anchorTutorial/feeRedeemCounter/node_modules/.bin/ts-mocha
> -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 'tests/**/*.ts'
>
> TypeError: Module
> "file:///Users/julia/Downloads/anchorTutorial/feeRedeemCounter/tsconfig.json"
> needs an import assertion of type "json"
> at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
> at validateAssertions (node:internal/modules/esm/assert:82:15)
> at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:24:3)
> at ESMLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:359:26)
> at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:280:58)
> at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:66:26)
> at ESMLoader.#createModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:297:17)
> at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:261:34)
> at async Promise.all (index 0)
> at ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:337:24)
> at importModuleDynamicallyWrapper (node:internal/vm/module:437:15)
> at formattedImport (/Users/julia/Downloads/anchorTutorial/feeRedeemCounter/node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/esm-utils.js:7:14)
> at Object.exports.requireOrImport (/Users/julia/Downloads/anchorTutorial/feeRedeemCounter/node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/esm-utils.js:48:32)
> at Object.exports.loadFilesAsync (/Users/julia/Downloads/anchorTutorial/feeRedeemCounter/node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/esm-utils.js:103:20)
> at singleRun (/Users/julia/Downloads/anchorTutorial/feeRedeemCounter/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:125:3)
> at Object.exports.handler (/Users/julia/Downloads/anchorTutorial/feeRedeemCounter/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run.js:374:5)
> error Command failed with exit code 1. info Visit
> https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this
> command. Error: Program address not found.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I fixed my own problem by running

> yarn add ts-mocha

Comment: Seems to be a version problem. Anchor init uses 8.0.0 and after doing this, updates to 10.0.0

Comment: If using a dependency management tool for a monorepo (such as lerna), use `yarn add ts-mocha -W` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
yarn add ts-mocha
```

This did not work for me. I deleted the `package-lock.json` and then updated the npm packages to the latest

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.3.4",
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.18",
    "chai": "^4.3.7",
    "mocha": "^10.2.0",
    "ts-mocha": "^10.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
```

then updated the provider code:

```
import * as anchor from "@project-serum/anchor";

const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
anchor.setProvider(provider);
```